# Как отобразить динамически генерируемый уровень игроку?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

В моей игре уровни генерируются программно из ранее заготовленных блоков.
Таким образом, когда загружается сцена, она, сама по себе, почти пустая (камера, интерфейс, парочка объектов, которые контролируют создание уровня).

Как только сцена загружена, начинается генерация уровня с некоторыми вычислениями, подгрузкой ресурсов, созданием префабов.

При смене сцен возникает проблема, что сама сцена загружается мгновенно, а генерация уровня приводит к зависанию игры. И так как все объекты создаются программно, то `LoadLevelAsync` никак тут не поможет...

Есть ли какой то способ дождаться полной генерации уровня, а потом показать его игроку?

Comment: Самый действенный вариант, который применяется в очень большом числе игр - сплэш скрин, какое-то изображение на весь экран (возможно анимированное), которое показывается до тех пор пока генерация вашего уровня не завершится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под зависанием подразумевается полная неотзывчивость игры, когда, к примеру, на Windows показывается сообщение "Приложение не отвечает", или вы про то, что игрок увидит недорегенерированный уровень?

Если первое, то распилите генерацию на различные фреймы, если оно действительно настолько долго выполняется. К примеру, если у вас вся генерация занимает секунд 5, можно разделить генерацию на 100 фреймов, чтобы каждый чанк вписывался в тайминги, выделенные на фрейм. Если у вас там какие-то операции, не связанные с компонентами Unity3d (к примеру, парсинг json'а, чтение с диска и т.п.), то их вообще можно в отдельный поток вынести.

Если второе, то можно на время генерации показывать какой-нибудь сплеш скрин.

Comment: Полная неотзывчивость. 
Но я воспользовался и первым и вторым советами) Разбил генерацию на "части" с помощью coroutines и, на время генерации, поставил сплеш скрин.
Спасибо за советы!)